# How can I replace all instances of * in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, replace

I'd like to remove all instances of '*' from my dataframe, pitcher, specifically in the 'Name' column.

```
     Rk     Name                  Team    IP   R
887  888.0  Huascar Ynoa\ynoahu01  ATL   3.0   6
888  889.0  Alex Young*\youngal01  ARI  34.2  10
```

I've tried the snippets below, as well as anything I could find only (regex=True and other variations). Also tried using a for loop on the strings individually, but each time I print either the new Series/Dataframe, the * are still there

```
pitcher = pitcher.replace('*', '')

pitcher['Name'] = pitcher['Name'].replace('*', '')

newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['newname'] = pitcher['Name'].replace('*', '')
```

The simplest idea would be great. I'm sure there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Something like `pitcher['Name'].str.replace('*', '')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `'*'` anywhere in the dataframe we'll first have to find all `string` columns and then replace the `'*'` there. Strings have the `object` type, so this will work in most trivial cases:

```
for c in pitcher.select_dtypes(['object']).columns:
    pitcher.loc[:,c] = pitcher.loc[:,c].str.replace('*','')
```

Please note that mixed type columns or other object type columns (dicts, lists etc.) are of `object` type too. In these cases we can use:

```
pitcher = pitcher.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('*','') if isinstance(x,str) else x)
```